# Add Action to ContactsContract list

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Created Intent based on ContactContract (load up Native Android Contact App) into an activity in an app. Is it possible to add an Action to the Action Bar versus building a separate List view. Trying to standardize on Android's interface

Here is the code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.contacts);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);  

    // ContentResolver for Contacts
    getContacts();
```

Answer (score 0):

You add actions to the Action bar by adding options menu items as "action items". See the documentation. Just like options menu items, you can associate an Intent with an action item.

However, why not just add an action to the list view itself: when users click a contact, your Intent fires. You can do this with setOnItemClickListener(). If you really want to have users click the item in the list, and then click an action item to send the Intent, use the item click listener to store the row id of the selected contact, then send the Intent from the action item listener.

To construct the content URI for the individual item, build up the URI by using ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI and the LOOKUP_ID value from the row backing the item. The method to use to combine these is android.net.Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri, String).

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I would like to add my own navigation icon to the action bar of the native Contact app started within my activity. Building an app for Android version 4.